# Rails route constraint not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, routes

I want to match all URLs that begin with `/company/`, so I have this route:

```
match '/*id' => 'high_voltage/pages#show', :constraints => { id: /^company\/.*/ }
```

But the constraint doesn't do anything. The URL `/abc` also matches this route and the `PagesController` throws an error.

How should I specify this?

I need the `id` parameter to contain `company/` in the beginning, so please don't say to just make the route `match '/company/*id'`. That will give the controller an `id` parameter without the `company/`.

***UPDATE***: I did try the regex above in normal Ruby and it works. I also tried without the ^ in front of company (though I do need company to be the first word), no luck.

***UPDATE 2***: It seems the problem is with the wildcard, do wildcard routes work with constraints? I can't get ANY constraint to work when there's a wildcard in the route.

***UPDATE 3***: Turns out this is simply a [bug in Ruby on Rails](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/7924#issuecomment-9421227).

Comment: Why does the id parameter need `/company` in it?

Comment: @RyanBigg - the reason id needs `company` (without the / in front) is that's how thoughtbot's High Voltage gem works. The id needs the full path.

Comment: One (potential) problem is that you can't anchor your regular expressions in routing constraints. Rails *should* be giving you an error when it encounters the `^`. Honestly? After looking into high-voltage, I would throw that gem out. It doing *so* little for you that it's not worth destroying your routing table to make it work. Rails already makes static pages very, *very* easy.

Comment: Make a `PagesController`, add `get "pages/:action" => "pages#action"` and you've pretty much done everything that Gem gives you.

Comment: As a final, final note, don't mix old/new hash syntax... `constraints: { id: /^company\/.*/ }` instead of `:constraints =>`...

Comment: @meagar - You may be right about the high-voltage gem, it does a little more for you in giving you named routes, but I'm also just very curious at least how to get this to work. In regards to the old/new hash syntax, I had an issue with making the `:constraints =>` into `constraints:`, though I just tried it and it worked. Anyway I also had tried just making everything hashrockets without benefit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted in the update, this is a bug in Rails.

Answer (score -2):

Looks like a syntax error. Try using `:constraints => {:id => /^company/.*/}`

edit: I just assumed ruby v 1.9.2